# How do I check if a file exists by trimming a given string?

Tags: bash, terminal

Lets say I have the following files `Foo-Bar1.mp3 Foo-Bar2.jpg Foo-Bar1.mp3 Foo-Bar1.mp4`
I want to download them so they are in a url like `www.example.com/1/Foo%20-Bar1.mp3`
I want to cut the URL so that I can use it to check if the file exists before I download it

```
if [ ! -f Foo-Bar1.mp3 ]; then
#Download it
fi`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parameter expansion to accomplish this :

```
 $ url='www.example.com/1/Foo%20-Bar1.mp3'
 $ name=${url##*/}
 $ echo $name
    Foo%20-Bar1.mp3
 $ echo ${name/\%20/}
     Foo-Bar1.mp3
```

Regards!

Note - As noted by @oguzismail you can use **echo -e ${name//%/\x}** to decode each url character.

Comment: You can use `echo -e ${name//%/\\x}` to decode every `%` encoded char.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the tip. Im adding your contribution.